# getting the zip file for kivy and its dependancies

Tags: python, kivy

I was reading a book on making multi-touch and cross platform apps and to do this i have to get the kivy library and all its dependancies but the official web site of kivy does not offer the zip file anymore. I would appreciate it if anyone can give me the zip files they already downloaded.

Comment: What are you using to build the cross platform apps? If you are using `buildozer` and/or `pyinstaller`, you just need to have `python` and `kivy` installed on your PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method of deployment was non conventionnal and a bit hard to maintain, now we advise people to use the standard python tools, which are pip and virtualenv, to install kivy, whatever the platform. See the installations instructions https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html